# Javascript TRUE and "true" why someone uses string instead of boolean?

Tags: javascript, string, boolean

I see in some javascript codes that people write something like this:

```
var myVar = "true";

//...

if(myVar == "true") {
     //...
}else{
     //...
}
```

Why people don't use TRUE or FALSE? As far as I know boolean type is obvious for browsers.

Or is just a poor code ... and try to never write in this way.

Comment: That's `true` and `false` actually (lower-case), but your analysis is right: better use actual booleans instead of strings.

Comment: And `var myVar = "false"; if (myVar) alert("O, hai!")` will show you alert as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just poor code. Try to never write in this way.

This kind of code is just horrible for maintainability. Both the `==` (instead of `===`) and the `true` as string.

<sub>PS: besides, `"true" == true // false`. For the `===` argument, it's simply because `true == 1 // true`, and a lot of others look alike stuff like this.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

You should not do this, unless you really expect a string that contains `true` for some reason :). But even in that case, using [strict equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use) (`===`) would be the right choice.

In the code example you are showing, this is simply a terrible way of writing code.

Comment: In that case you should use strict equality to make it clear to anyone reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

It's just poor code, as you say.

A "real" developer never writes `if (condition == true)`, but only `if (condition)`

Could also be written `if (true == condition)`. This is called Yoda style and is designed to prevent unwanted assignment of variables if you mistakenly write `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: If you are talking about "real" developers, mentioning `===` would be worth it when testing for `true` :).

Comment: Agreed. I especially do this in PHP when testing for failures.